# Optimize Powershell Script for Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

I have to update item in a SharePoint with over 200k items. My initial thoughts is to use the Powershell script below

```
$resultItems = $list.GetItems(SPQUERY_OBJECT)

foreach($item in $resultItems)
{
     $item["Collect"] = "Yes"
    $item.Update()
}
```

Since I am dealing with a very huge list, is there a way I could optimize this code for better performance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the paging concept in particular combining the RowLimit and the ListItemCollectionPosition property of the Query object.
You can find on the following link how that could work on c# (not a PowerShell example but it should be simple to replicate that on PowerShell)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.listitemcollectionposition.aspx